# Upgrading io.projectreactor version from 2.0.x to 3.0.4 - Using Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have an issue while trying to make the upgrade.

Currently i'm using version 2.0.x, and in particular -

```
reactor.bus
reactor.rx.Stream
reactor.rx.Streams
reactor.core.processor.RingBufferProcessor
reactor.fn.Consumer
```

I'm using maven, and i have a single dependency regarding 'projectreactor' -

```
<groupId>io.projectreactor.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>reactor-spring-core</artifactId>
```

When upgrading to version 3.0.4.RELEASE, in order to keep using all the things i used before, i need to explicitly import -

```
<groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
<artifactId>reactor-bus</artifactId>
```

And

```
<groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
<artifactId>reactor-stream</artifactId>
```

but i'm still missing

```
reactor.core.processor.RingBufferProcessor
reactor.fn.Consumer
```

and i'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reactor.rx.Stream -> reactor.core.publisher.Flux
reactor.rx.Streams -> reactor.core.publisher.Flux
reactor.rx.Promise -> reactor.core.publisher.Mono and reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor
reactor.core.processor.RingBufferProcessor -> reactor.core.publisher.TopicProcessor
reactor.fn.Consumer -> java.util.function.Consumer (Java 8)
```

There is no new spring module since spring 5 directly includes Reactor support with these new types.

As for reactor-bus :
By design now all stream routes (Flux/Mono chains) are typed, so dynamic routing is not part of our features yet. Still there are alternative in a typed way, for instance :

```
ReplayProcessor<MyEvent> rp = ReplayProcessor.create();
Flux<MyEvent> interest1 = rp.filter(ev -> filterInterest1(ev));
Flux<MyEvent> interest2 = rp.filter(ev -> filterInterest2(ev));
Flux<MyEvent> interest1_2 = rp.filter(ev -> filterInterest1(ev) || filterInterest2(ev));

interest1.subscribe(doSomethingForInterest1);
interest2.subscribe(doSomethingForInterest2);
interest1_2.subscribe(doSomethingForInterest1_2);

rp.onNext(new MyEvent("interest1")); //subscriber 1 and 3 react
rp.onNext(new MyEvent("interest1")); //subscriber 1 and 3 react
rp.onNext(new MyEvent("interest2")); //subscriber 2 and 3 react
rp.onNext(new MyEvent("interest4")); // buffered until interest subscriber because ReplayProcessor

//shutdown/cleanup/close
rp.onComplete();
```

I have found this on github which seems to fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

`reactor.fn.Consumer` is replaced by Java 8 `java.util.function.Consumer`.

As for `RingBufferProcessor` you have to pick one of [new processors](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core#hot-publishing--processors) all using ring buffer.

`Dispatcher`s are now [Schedulers](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html) that use Java's `Executor`s under the hood.

Comment: What abount RingBufferDispatcher? I am using the EventBus and it seems that everything there will be deprecated soon.. Makes me wonder about this library.

Comment: @AdamBerlin I've added a note about dispatchers. Not sure about EventBus but the core library has dropped many custom implementations moving to standard Java 8 classes instead.

Comment: @AdmBerlin note that 3.x, compared to 2.x, is a very big paradigm shift, now focusing more deeply on reactive programming and the reactive streams specification.